# Should a library used solely by userscripts be minified?

Tags: javascript, require, userscripts, tampermonkey

In my userscripts, I often `@require` a self-written javascript library. I'm wondering how much load this generates. Is the library (re-)loaded every time a userscript is executed? Or is it only loaded the first time, and then cached? Would minifying it make a significant difference?

I looked at the [tampermonkey docs](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_require), but they don't go into detail about this. They only state that the library *"is loaded and executed before the script itself starts running"*.

How important is it to minify this library? Since I make changes to the library fairly often, I would prefer to avoid the extra step of minifying it every time. What are the advantages and disadvantages of minifying such a library?

Comment: Since I'm gathering quite a few "opinion-based" close votes, would it help if I rephrased to question to "What are the (dis-)advantages of minifying a library used only by userscripts"?

Comment: Aran-Fey, it might. But, I've seen a few of those kinds of phrasings get closed too.  Anyway, this question has merit, in my *opinion*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, the precise details of how often a script is checked change. But here's how it usually/is supposed/used to work:

1. When the **script is installed**, the `@require` library is fetched and saved to disk (nowadays stored as part of extension data in a LevelDB database).
2. When the **`@require` string is changed**, the script is refetched.
3. (¿Maybe?) the script is refetched if the **script itself is updated** (version changes)
4. At one time, Tampermonkey may have been fetching the script at every script run?!
5. Tampermonkey used to fetch `@require`d scripts, with `file://` URLs, at every run as an aid to developers.  But this stopped working and not sure what the current status is.

The point is that **nominally, a required file (with an off-machine URL) should be run from disk or cache and be very fast.**

So trade-offs:

**Don't minimize because:**

- Normally makes no performance difference, in a userscript scenario.
- Scripts are easier to debug.
- Fewer steps in the develop/deploy process.

**Do minimize because:**

- The `@require`d script has a large install base and hosting server load is a concern.
- The file is large enough that minimizing can save significant space, say 100K.
- The file is also used "normally" (EG by `<script>` tags) -- so bandwidth is much more critical. (Not everyone has high-speed connections, etc.)
- You want to make it just a smidge harder for someone to "steal" your precious code. (This reason listed for completeness, I do not recommend it.)